# Preventing Jquery .click toggle function from running over and over with excess clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im building a .clicktoggle function in jQuery and for the life of me i can't get a .stop like effect on it, basically i don't want it to play over and over if mash clicked.

I want it to be applied the the function so its self contained, that's where im stuck.

[**JS fiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/jqdLz6h2/2/)

```
    (function($) {
  $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
    var funcs = [func1, func2];
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
      var data = $(this).data();
      var tc = data.toggleclicked;
      $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
      data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$('div').clickToggle(function() {
  $('.testsubject').fadeOut(500);
}, function() {
  $('.testsubject').fadeIn(500);
});
```

---

```
    <div class="clickme">click me fast</div>
<div class="testsubject">how do i stop it playing over and over if you click alot</div>
```

Toggle .click seems like something alot of people would use so i thought it might be useful to ask it here

Comment: Does this mean you want to ignore all clicks while the fade is in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clicked = false;
var doing = false;

$(".clickme").click(function(e) {
  if (doing) {
    return;
  } else {
    doing = true;
  }
  doing = true;
  clicked = !clicked;
  if (clicked) {
    $('.testsubject').fadeOut(700, function() {
        doing = false
    });
  } else {
        $('.testsubject').fadeIn(700, function() {
        doing = false;
    });
  }
});
```

This example is a simple toggle which only allows you to click when it is not doing anything. I explained on IRC, but as an example here, the function only runs when `doing` is set to false, which only happens when it's set after `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut`'s callback function thingymajigger.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @4castle your one is for fades only?

Comment: So is this one... It's using the exact same callbacks and everything.

Comment: @4castle i was of the impression i can add  "   function() {
        doing = false   " to more then just fades?

Comment: Sorry, this one was the approved answer on IRC already. He kinda wanted to give kudos where it was already given, but in a more physical form.

Comment: No. The callback for when it's completed is for fades only. It's a jQuery feature of fades.

Comment: @Timothy So you're telling me you selected this answer as correct just because you know this guy? But then my identical answer was denied even though it was 8 minutes earlier and you even reviewed it?

Comment: @4castle he answered on irc before your post.

Comment: That's fine. I'm not really upset about the timing or that his was selected. I'm just upset that mine was wrong but his was right? Is your question actually answered right now? Or did you just select it based on his word?

Comment: @4castle he explained it better with logic then you, and you have way more rep already, don't be a REP addict

Comment: I'm not questioning the quality of this answer at all. I don't care about the rep. I just want to know if this answer actually solved the problem or if this entire post is fabricated.

Comment: @4castle the way both of you solved it is not ideal but yes this should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

By adding a check to a boolean variable `fadeInProgress`, you can choose to only queue the animation if `fadeInProgress` is `false`. It then sets the value to `true` and executes the animation. When the animation is completed, set the value to `false`.

```
var fadeInProgress = false;
$('div').clickToggle(function() {
  if (!fadeInProgress) {
    fadeInProgress = true;
    $('.testsubject').fadeOut(700, function(){fadeInProgress = false;});
  }
}, function() {
  if (!fadeInProgress) {
    fadeInProgress = true;
    $('.testsubject').fadeIn(700, function(){fadeInProgress = false;});
  }
});
```